# Can you help me alter my regular expression to include a particular range of unicode characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, unicode

I am allowing users to create comments within my app.
I have created a javascript regular expression which matches the characters I would like to allow within the comment.
This includes basic latin characters, some Latin-1 and Latin Extended-A characters, some extra symbols and the carraige return and new line characters as we can see in the regex here:

```
commentRegex = /^([A-Za-z0-9\u00C0-\u017F\u20AC\u2122\u2150\u00A9 \/.,\-_$!\'&*()="?#+%:;\<\[\]\r\r\n]{1,2000})$/;
```

I then use the regular expression to validate the input as follows:

```
function validateInput(inputValue, regularExpression){
    var inputIsValid = regularExpression.test(inputValue);
    return inputIsValid;
}

var commentIsValid = validateInput(comment_input_text, commentRegex);
if(!commentIsValid){
    //comment does not contain valid characters. Notify the user.       
    //do not submit form
}else{
    //comment does contain valid characters. allow form to be submitted
}
```

I would like to allow emojis in the comment so I have researched what the unicode range is for emojis and found [this article](http://crocodillon.com/blog/parsing-emoji-unicode-in-javascript) which states that emojis can be matched with the following ranges:

```
var ranges = [
  '\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]', // U+1F300 to U+1F3FF
  '\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f]', // U+1F400 to U+1F64F
  '\ud83d[\ude80-\udeff]'  // U+1F680 to U+1F6FF
];
```

I would like to add these ranges into my current regex however I am unsure of exactly the right way to format this. (Regular expressions are not my forte)
  I have tried adding them in (after the other unicode values) as follows

```
commentRegex = /^([A-Za-z0-9\u00C0-\u017F\u20AC\u2122\u2150\u00A9\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f]\ud83d[\ude80-\udeff] \/.,\-_$!\'&*()="?#+%:;\<\[\]\r\r\n]{1,2000})$/;
```

However the regex doesn't work at all then. I'd appreciate your help to format it the right way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a direct response to your question, I would propose the following regex:

`/^(?:[A-Za-z0-9\u00C0-\u017F\u20AC\u2122\u2150\u00A9 \/.,\-_$!\'&*()="?#+%:;\<\[\]\r\r\n]|(?:\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff])|(?:\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f\ude80-\udeff])){1,2000}$/`

But really, this require some explanations before you go on... And first of all, let's get back to some definition... You probably know some of these, but they are really necessary for the answer to actually make sense.

Regex are state machines that consume "characters". Sounds simple enough, but various regex engines have different definition of what is a "character", with two predominant variants: either a character is a single byte, or a character is a UTF16 code unit (that is each sequence of 16 bits when the text is encoded in UTF16). JavaScript use the second variant.

Emoji characters require two consecutive UTF16 code unit; that is the reason why, in a UTF16-based regex, they must be matched as two consecutive characters (for example `\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]`). The two characters form a pair, and that sequence must be maintained in the regex.

In a regex, a character class (for example `[a-z0-9 ,-]`) will match a single input character, given that it is contained in the specified characters list. There is no sequence and no ordering on the characters inside that class: at most one character will get matched. Emojis can't therefore be matched correctly simply by including their UTF16 code unit to a long list of accepted characters (well, doing so would actually result in a regex that accepts all valid input, but also accept many invalid input).

A character class can equivalently be replaced by a long list of "alternatives" particles: `(?:a|b|c|...|y|z|0|1...|9| |,|-)`. Note here that I used a non-capturing group, that is `(?:...)`, instead of a capturing group `(...)`; this is desirable whenever you do not intend to refer to the value of a group, since there is a performance cost associated to capturing that value. Indeed, a long list of alternatives is far less efficient than a character class particle; there is however an advantage doing so: alternatives allow matching for sequences of multiple characters. For example, one could say `(?:apple|banana|cherry|...)`. In this form, it is now possible to correctly match emoji characters: `(?:\ud83c\udf00|\ud83c\udf01|\ud83c\udf02...\ud83c\udfff|...)`. But expending all alternatives this would result in a ridiculously long and hard to maintain regex. So you will definitely want to mix character class and alternatives appropriately.

So your regex will basically have the following form:

```
(?: [all acceptable single characters] |
    \ud83c [all acceptable low surrogates for pairs starting with d83c] |
    \ud83d [all acceptable low surrogates for pairs starting with d83d] )
```

From this point, I simply plugged in the character classes that you provided in your question, and removed extra spaces...

In your question, your regex more over was surrounded by `^(...){1,2000}$`, meaning that the regex would only match if the string, from beginning (that is `^`) to the end (that is `$`) contained between 1 and 2000 of the allowed characters. Adding this around the previously constructed pattern should give the regex I gave at the beginning of my answer. I should however warn you that this might not be the most appropriate way to test for the length of the input string. Why are you imposing the 2000 characters limit? Does that limit actually applies to your storage model? If so, then you should definitely consider the fact that emojis actually takes up two "characters"... And the relation will be even more complex if your backend store values with UTF8 encoding... You should therefore consider checking for the length of the input text with a distinct test, written directly in JavaScript, rather than using a regex repetition specifier. If you decide to so, replace the `{1,2000}` by a `*` suffix (which simply means "any number of repetition").

Comment: thank you. this looks good. can you explain to me what the ?: means? and does the | symbol mean "OR"?

Comment: thank you for your explanation. This regex works perfect. Its allowing most emojis now however some wont go through. I musn't have included the full range. do you have any idea about that? Also I notice on the end of my original regex I have a bracket ) between the } and the $ like so: {1,2000})$/; however you have the bracket beforehand as follows: ){1,2000}$/ .. is this a mistake in my original regex? thanks

Comment: The surrounding parentheses in your original regex were useless. The parentheses in my proposed regex are required to make sure that the `{1,2000}` suffix affect the whole alternatives group.

Comment: I just saw your edit about the length of the input string. yes in my database I have set this field to varchar(2000) and the collation is utf8mb4. Ok so I will look into checking the length of the input text with javascript instead.. and then I will replace the {1,2000} by a * as you say. thank you very much

Comment: I have put a max length of 2000 (on the html form field instead of using javascript). maxlength="2000" This way if the user enters for example 1000 emojis it wont allow any more input (as they count as two characters) and so I don't have to be worried about the text exceeding storage space of 2000 characters. Do you think this sounds like a good solution?

Comment: I wasn't sure about it, but it indeed appears that the HTML5 specification explicitly mention that the length of a field's value (for the purpose of the `maxlength` and `minlength` limits), should be determined by the number of UTF16 code-units. So you are right saying that emoji count as 2 characters, and most importantly, that behavior should be consistant among browsers. Yet, after checking the MySQL manual, a `VARCHAR(2000)` column with `utf8mb4` encoding actually allows for 2000 unicode characters (that is, it could contain 2000 emoji characters)…

Comment: One way or another, you should always duplicate validation checks on the server side. You do not want your code to crash or behave incorrectly if a user somehow gets around your client side validations. Client-side-only validations is a frequent source of security problems in web applications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132225/discussion-between-sarah-and-jwatkins).